# SWTbot - How to build a project

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, swtbot

In my SWTbot test i'm trying to create a C project and then build it so i can run it later .
I tried

```
bot.menu("Project").menu("Build Project").click();
```

or also

```
bot.menu("Project").menu("Build All").click();
```

and i got `WidgetNotFound Exception`.

help please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Found it ! SWTbot finds the wrong "Project" menu item. It finds the one 
that is located in Search -> Text . to do this we must specifie the depth of the menu we are looking for and it gives us :

`bot.menu("Project", 1);`

Comment: Thanks for answering your question! Saved a lot of time!
Thanks!